# Making a program which detects changes in a particular dictionary, and if changes are there then starts the next code

Tags: python

I want to create a program that detects a change in a particular dictionary and if the change is there starts the next code.

By the help of Google found this code:
(below is greeksforgeeks code)

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
  
  
class OnMyWatch:
    # Set the directory on watch
    watchDirectory = "/give / the / address / of / directory"
  
    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()
  
    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.watchDirectory, recursive = True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Observer Stopped")
  
        self.observer.join()
  
  
class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
  
    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None
  
        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            # Event is created, you can process it now
            print("Watchdog received created event - % s." % event.src_path)
        elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            # Event is modified, you can process it now
            print("Watchdog received modified event - % s." % event.src_path)
              
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    watch = OnMyWatch()
    watch.run()
```

It works fine but the problem is it works in loop.

Comment: It sounds like you want to monitor filesystem changes, so that your code only gets notified when a file changes. That is platform-specific. You can find two approaches for Windows from this old link: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html It was written for Python 2 so you'll have to make changes. `lib2to3` should be able to manage that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more simpler:

```
import os
path=r'your\path'
b=os.listdir(path)
path_len_org=int(len(b))
while True:
      b=os.listdir(path)
      path_len_final=int(len(b))
      if path_len_org<path_len_final:
              print("A file is added")
              break
      if path_len_org>path_len_final:
              print("A file is removed")
              break
```

Answer (score 1):

i got the solution, thanks to @BoarGules

> HERES THE CODE

```
path_to_watch = "your/path"
print('Your folder path is"',path,'"')
before = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
while 1:
        after = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
        added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
        if added:
                 print("Added: ", ", ".join (added))
                 break
        else:
             before = after
```

I have edited the code, the orginal code is available at
http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

The original code was made in python 2x so you need to convert it in python 3.

NOTE:-

- WHEN EVER YOU ADD ANY FILE IN PATH, IT PRINTS THE TEXT AND BREAKS, AND IF NO FILES ARE ADDED THEN IT WOULD CONTINUE TO RUN.